# Anonymous access over SSL

Tags: tls, http, vpn

I am using a paid VPN service and I just realized IP privacy does not exist at all when the connection is made over SSL.

If I Google "what is my ip" using the HTTP version of Google, it will give me the IP behind the VPN. But as soon as I use the SSL encrypted version of Google, it reveals my real IP address.

Is it possible to stop that from happening? End-to-end encrypted communications is not my concern, I just don't want the other end to have my real IP.

Comment: I believe further clarification is required to help diagnose this issue, such as the VPN provider in use. It would also be useful to understand if you have any other proxies configured (checking your browser proxy settings, or confirming if you are using something like Fiddler?)

Answer (score 3):

A VPN works by tunnelling connections initiated by your PC through the VPN, so that they come out on the Internet at the VPN endpoint and not at your PC's primary Internet access point. This happens at the IP level, there is no difference between HTTP and HTTPS in this regard. So the behavior you describe indicates that your HTTPS traffic is not going through your VPN, i.e. your VPN setup is misconfigured.

If you want all traffic to go through your VPN (except obviously for the VPN tunnel), it's best to configure it at the IP routing level: make sure your default route goes through the VPN and only the VPN entry point is routed through your Internet gateway. If you've set up a VPN only for web access through a proxy setting, make sure to activate it for HTTPS as well as HTTP.